# How to use group by with Self join

Tags: sql

I have table like this

- Acc,  amount, x, Name, Time
- 1, 100, dep, bbb, 10
- 1, 200, dep, bbb, 10
- 1, 80, wit, bbb, 10
- 1, 90, wit, bbb, 10
- 2, 100, dep, bbb, 20
- 2, 101, wit, bbb, 20
- 1, 100, dep, ccc, 10
- 1, 150, wit, ccc, 10

From this I want to show a table like

- Name, Acc, Time, dep_amt, wid_amt, profit
- bbb, 1, 10, 300, 170, 130
- bbb, 2, 20, 100, 101, -1
- ccc, 1, 10, 100, 150, -50

So, I tried self join

```
SELECT a.Name, a.Acc, a.Time, a.Amount as dep_amt, new.Amount as wid_amt, (a.Amount-new.Amount) as profit
FROM all_data as a, all_data as new
where a.Time = new.Time
and a.name = new.name
and a.acc =new.acc
and a.x= "dep”
and new.x="wit"
```

But , I can't use Group by(error contains nonaggregated column) with it and this sql results a table with many rows. How to do???

Comment: If you group by something you’ll have to aggregate the results. You haven’t shown how you want to group it so impossible to advice. But the idea is this: if you group by name, for example, then which time should be given for that name? Or amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like conditional aggregation, not a self-join:

```
select Name, Acc, Time,
       sum(case when x = 'dep' then amount else 0 end) as dep_amt,
       sum(case when x = 'wit' then amount else 0 end) as wit_amt,
       sum(case when x = 'dep' then amount 
                when x = 'wit' then - amount
                else 0
           end) as profit
from t
group by Name, Acc, Time;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6ea95d08dec09dad035894489d15c383) is a db<>fiddle.

The self-join doesn't work because you have multiple "dep" and "wit" rows in each group.  Within each group, you get a Cartesian product of those rows, resulting in errors in the total calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT name,
       acc,
       time,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN x = 'dep' THEN
               amount
             ELSE
               0
           END) dep_amt,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN x = 'wit' THEN
               amount
             ELSE
               0
           END) dep_wit,
       sum(CASE
             WHEN x = 'dep' THEN
               amount
             ELSE
               0
           END)
       -
       sum(CASE
             WHEN x = 'wit' THEN
               amount
             ELSE
               0
           END) profit
       FROM all_data
       GROUP BY name,
                acc,
                time;
```